# Why does my code not segment the characters of the input image?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, ocr, image-segmentation

I am trying to do character segmentation from an image, but the output is not getting segmented.

That's my new_input image:

[new input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnG2f.jpg)

That's my code for segmenting characters:

```
word = cv2.imread('../input/word-image/word.PNG',0)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1)
ax1.imshow(word, cmap="gray")
# the next two lines is based on the assumptions that the width of
# a license plate should be between 5% and 15% of the license plate,
# and height should be between 35% and 60%
# this will eliminate some
character_dimensions = (0.35*word.shape[0], 0.60*word.shape[0], 0.05*word.shape[1], 0.15*word.shape[1])
min_height, max_height, min_width, max_width = character_dimensions

characters = []
counter=0
column_list = []
for regions in regionprops(word):
    y0, x0, y1, x1 = regions.bbox
    region_height = y1 - y0
    region_width = x1 - x0

    if region_height > min_height and region_height < max_height and region_width > min_width and region_width < max_width:
        roi = word[y0:y1, x0:x1]

        # draw a red bordered rectangle over the character.
        rect_border = patches.Rectangle((x0, y0), x1 - x0, y1 - y0, edgecolor="red",
                                       linewidth=2, fill=False)
        ax1.add_patch(rect_border)

        # resize the characters to 20X20 and then append each character into the characters list
        resized_char = resize(roi, (20, 20))
        characters.append(resized_char)

        # this is just to keep track of the arrangement of the characters
        column_list.append(x0)
# print(characters)
plt.show()
```

That's the current output:

[image: Output]

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops):

> Measure properties of labeled image regions.

You don't feed a proper labeled image, but your input is interpreted as one, since you have several gray values due to the aliasing. Debug `regions` inside your loop, and you'll see, that a lot of regions are detected. They're all dismissed due to your assumptions on width and height.

So, the first step would be to generate a proper labeled image, e.g. using [`cv2.connectedComponents`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaedef8c7340499ca391d459122e51bef5). Therefore, you'd need to (inverse) binarize your input image beforehand. Having the `labels` image, you can directly proceed with your loop. Nevertheless, I would dismiss all assumptions on width and height here.

That'd be the modified code:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches
from skimage.measure import regionprops
from skimage.transform import resize

# Read image as grayscale
word = cv2.imread('pFLpN.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Inverse binarize image, and find connected components
thr = cv2.threshold(word, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
labels = cv2.connectedComponents(thr)[1]

# Maybe leave out any assumptions on the width and height...

# Prepare outputs
plt.figure(figsize=(18, 9))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1), plt.imshow(word, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Original image')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2), plt.imshow(thr, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Binarized image')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3), plt.imshow(labels), plt.title('Connected components')
ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, 4), plt.imshow(word, cmap='gray')

# Iterate found connected components as before
# (Without checking width and height...)
characters = []
counter = 0
column_list = []
for regions in regionprops(labels):
    y0, x0, y1, x1 = regions.bbox
    region_height = y1 - y0
    region_width = x1 - x0
    roi = word[y0:y1, x0:x1]
    rect_border = patches.Rectangle((x0, y0), x1 - x0, y1 - y0, edgecolor='red',
                                    linewidth=2, fill=False)
    ax[0].add_patch(rect_border)

    resized_char = resize(roi, (20, 20))
    characters.append(resized_char)

    column_list.append(x0)

plt.title('Segmented characters')
plt.tight_layout(), plt.show()
```

And, that'd be the output:

[image: Output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.2
Matplotlib:    3.4.2
OpenCV:        4.5.2
scikit-image:  0.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: That was helpful!! How can I print images of individual characters of out it?

Comment: What do you mean by "print"? You already have `roi = word[y0:y1, x0:x1]` which is a cropped character from `word`. Save `roi` to some image for example. Or do some additional `plt.imshow(roi)` if you want to display the single characters.

Comment: Hey ! When I try to input different image , it does not get segmented. Please have a look at the new image which I input. I have edited in in my question posted. What can be the reason for the same?!

Comment: Because your initial image had perfect white background, while your new image has some white-ish/gray-ish background. As for every image processing task, you need to adapt the pre-processing when the input changes. If you need a more general solution, provide more input examples in the beginning! For that new image, you can try `thr = cv2.threshold(word, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]`, which will also work for the initial image. But it's not guaranteed to work with your next 6 or 7 images...

Comment: This code draws bounding boxes on connected characters. But the are even characters in my language where not all characters have connected components! What should I do in that Case???

Comment: That highly depends on the appearance. For example, if the parts of a single character are vertically stacked like in the letter `i`, you could perform morphological closing with a vertical kernel only to connect those parts. If you have specific examples you can't get working, ask a new question.